# Trouble with VS.PHP installing it's own Apache server

Tags: php, visual-studio-2008

I tried installing VS.PHP some time ago. I was intent on seeing how it works with my current setup.

I immediately encountered trouble: none of my sites wanted to render.

On windows, I'm using WAMP to run my PHP sites. VS.PHP seems to have installed its own Apache server. What I want is to have VS.PHP use my existing environment. How can I make it work that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its really using apache, you just need to locate the config files and set them up so they match your old dev environment.

Running `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` from the vs debugger should show you were the php.ini and apache config are.

Once you locate the apache config, make sure the doc_root is set to point to the same location as the wamp install.

Comment: I don't want it to just match my current environment, I want to use only my current environment and not install stuff without asking me. It does let Visual Studio write PHP, but it doesn't say what is needed in order to do so...